# Links on element become unclickable when stacked behind other (fixed) element

Tags: html, css, overlapping

I'm puzzled! The green menu is stacked behind the white header with search field. This is needed to display the page correctly, but now the green menus links become unclickable.

The white header is `position: fixed;`. The green menu is not fixed but has `z-index -1` because apparently this is the only way to stack it behind the white header.

How do I make the links clickable?

**Edit:**
I tried `z-index: 99;` aswell as `z-index: -99;` for both elements. Literally the only way to stack the green menu behind the white header is to use a negative z-index number for the green menu.

**Edit 2:**
I also tried using `opacity: .99;` for the white header but no results.

[image]

```
.header {
    margin: 32px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(55,175,75,1.00);
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(55,175,75,1.00);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}

#menu {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 107px;
    min-height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(55,175,75,1.00);
    border: 1px solid rgba(55,175,75,1.00);
    border-radius: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set z-index for **.header** as 2 and for **#menu** as 1